# How to figure it out 2 series for convergence / divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

guys ... I have 2 series to figure it out if they are convergent or divergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{n+3}{n}\right)}{3\cdot2^{n}}$$. My question is, how to determine if they are convergent or divergent. Which value is the sum of these to sums?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to figure it out the $\left|a_n\right| = \dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}$. So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}\right| = 0$. For second I don't know how to start ...

Comment: How to get next steps?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- For the alternating series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}$, use Leibniz'criterion. To show the fraction decreases to $0$ without derivatives, you can rewrite it as
  $$\frac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}=\frac 1n\,\frac{3n-1}{n+1}$$
  and use that a homographic function $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is increasing if the determinant $\;\begin{vmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{vmatrix}>0$, decreasing if it is $<0$.
- For the second series, use *equivalence*:
  \begin{align}
  &&&\ln\Bigl(\frac{n+3}n\Bigr)=\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{3}n\Bigr)\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac 3n\\
  &\text{so that }&&\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{n+3}{n}\right)}{3\cdot2^{n}}\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n\,2^n}<\frac1{2^n}\qquad &&\qquad
  \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For the first series you can use the general result $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n=-\ln(2)$$

Whose convergence is obtained by the criteria on alternated series:

- it is alternated sign
- absolute value is decreasing

The value can be calculated by comparison with an $\frac 1t$ integral or by Riemann sums, there are plenty of links to this one on the site.

Now, note that any $\dfrac{an+b}{n^2+n}$ can be decompsed into $\dfrac bn+\dfrac {a-b}{n+1}$.

Thus $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{an+b}{n(n+1)}=b\times(-\ln(2))+(a-b)\times(\ln(2)-1)=(b-a)+(a-2b)\ln(2)$

For the second one, I doubt you can find a closed form for $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{2^n}\approx 0.508$

Anyway, the convergence of this series is immediate by comparison or by the ratio test.

And similarly to the previous exercise, we can express the result in function of $S$.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{n+3}n)}{3\cdot 2^n}=\frac 13\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(8\frac{\ln(n+3)}{2^{n+3}}-\frac{\ln(n)}{2^{n}}\right)=\cdots=\frac 13\big(7S-2\ln(2)-\ln(3)\big)$